# Boostrap 4 - items aligment on mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

A newbie question, but I'm fighting with this almost two days.
I have problem with putting the title in separate line, and two buttons in the other line.
Right now this three elements are in each line.
My goal is to have title on top, and two buttons in line on the bottom of the navbar.
https://www.codeply.com/go/bUI3pKQmR6

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: please add your html + css code

Comment: Can you post your current HTML and CSS that's generating the layout on the attached screenshot?

Comment: Sorry I forget.
https://www.codeply.com/go/bUI3pKQmR6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this css to position the button 10px from the bottom and the title on the left below 745px, which is when it becomes 2 lines:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 745px) {
.navbar {
height: 100px;
}

.navbar-brand {
position: absolute;
left: 28px;
top: 10px;
}

.dropdown ,ml-auto {
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
right: 28px;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
}
}
```

Edit: I added css to set a height for the navbar and position the dropdown button on the right.

Comment: Nah, isn't good. Look:|
https://www.codeply.com/go/bUI3pKQmR6

Comment: I suspect that it's because there is no other css in the fiddle other than the one above. Anyways I added css to set a height for the navbar and position the dropdown button on the right so it works even in the fiddle as all 4 elements (the bar, the title, the button and the dropdown) are all resized or positioned  with this css.